# At the sight of blackbirds

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

In...

```
At the sight of blackbirds
Flying in the green light,
Even the bawds of euphony
Would cry out sharply.
(Wallace Stevens)
```

.. is it that (1) the bawds of euphony are seeing  the blackbirds flying in green light and because of that, would cry out sharply, or (2) the bawds of euphony are seen by the blackbirds and because of that, would cry out sharply, or (3) it is ambiguous, both interpretations are possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only the first interpretation is likely. Here's [a useful exegesis of the entire stanza from The Schmoop](http://www.shmoop.com/thirteen-ways-of-looking-at-a-blackbird/section-x-summary.html) (honestly, I'd never heard of that site before I joined this one, but they do good work).

Comment: The bawds of euphony...good times.

Comment: @Mitch what'd you expect, this is 1920s :)

Comment: @DanBron Surely it cannot be happening that the bawds are seeing the blackbirds, can it? Otherwise why would the verb *would* be used. It is a case of *At the sight of xyz, even Charles would laugh*. It doesn't mean that Charles laughed, but the author merely surmises that even he would if xyz were the case. So, in my view none of the interpretations are possible.

Comment: @ws2 Worth your time to read the short article I linked to. Yes, the crass and tasteless bawds, who can usually only enjoy the baldest and coarsest of beauties (*euphonies*), they, even they, would be moved by the sight of a blackbird flying in a green light. They (would) see the birds, not the other way around. It's unambiguous (unlike the source of the *green light*).

Comment: Thanks! so the bawds are (or would be) seeing the birds, not the other way round.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because poetry interpretation is off-topic.

Comment: @curiousdannii The question is not about interpretation in that sense, it is about the (literal) meaning of a complex sentence. You could just as well close it, however, as (1) I asked it in the wrong site (should be English Language Learners), and (2) the question has served its purpose as the comments above already provide a sufficient answer (Thanks all, especially Dan Bron) [not that I wouldn't appreciate additional elaborations etc].

Comment: @DanBron Two different grammar issues got conflated in this question. You have dealt with the matter of subject/object and rightly adjudged the *bawds* as subject and *sight of the blackbirds* as predicate. I interpreted the question as being about *would*. It wasn't happening, but *would happen IF...*.

Answer (score -1):

It's the first.  "At the sight of blackbirds" means it's the blackbirds being viewed.  "Sighted by blackbirds" would mean that the birds are doing the viewing.

Comment: You're right, but how does someone who doesn't already know you're right, know you're right? In brief: please [edit] your answer to add support, corroboration, references, citations of authority, whatever. We don't encourage "Trust me, I know whereof I speak" answers here on StackExchange.